# How do I make a self-signed certificate persist in nixos?

Tags: nixos

I have a nix expression that builds a virtualbox vm.  As part of that process, I install a self-signed ssl certificate via

```
certfile = builtins.readFile ./certificate.crt
security.pki.certificates = [ certfile ];
```

That works fine.  The problem is if I want to run a nixos-rebuild to reconfigure the vm.  Since I no longer have access to the original certfile from the vm build process (because I'm running in the vm, not on the machine where I built the vm), I can't just include the file again through the same mechanism.

I've come up with three ideas on how to do this:

1. During the vm build process, place an extra copy of the cert under /root in the vm.  Then I can just use this in my configuration.nix to pull in the certificate again:

   ```
   security.pki.certificates = [ /root/cert ];
   ```
2. Since the certificate is always available for http download from an internal server, I could somehow use fetchUrl in the configuration.nix to download it every time I do a nixos-rebuild.  I suppose the only downside to this would be introducing an external dependency.
3. Since the certificate is in /etc/ssl/ca-certificates.crt, I could somehow extract it from that file as part ofthe rebuild process and then feed it to security.pki.certificates again.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify what `certfile` looks like in the first line. If it's a variable thats populated with a `builtins.readFile`, you can skip that step and just populate the variable yourself.

```
$> nixos-option security.pki.certificates
Value:
[ "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... edited for brevity .... " ]

Default:
[ ]

Example:
[ "NixOS.org\n=========\n-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIGUDCCBTigAwIBAgIDD8KWMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMIGMMQswCQYDVQQGEwJJ\nTDEWMBQGA1UEChMNU3RhcnRDb20gTHRkLjErMCkGA1UECxMiU2VjdXJlIERpZ2l0\n...\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n" ]

Description:

A list of trusted root certificates in PEM format.

Declared by:
  "/etc/nixos/nixpkgs/nixos/modules/security/ca.nix"

Defined by:
  "/etc/nixos/user.nix
```

So, setting `security.pki.certificates [ "insert certificate here" ];` would eliminate the file dependency and then the configuration is self contained.

Otherwise, if you wanted to keep the content out of the configuration, you'd need to create packaging/a derivation for it and add it to the store.

Comment: Sorry about that.  You are right, certfile is a variable that is populated with builtins.readFile.

Answer (score 2):

i'm assuming you're deploying with nixops, but even if you don't you can create arguments for any nix script.

i did something similar in my server config [here](https://github.com/garbas/dotfiles/blob/master/nixops/floki.nix) and then you use arguments as described [here](http://nixos.org/nixops/manual/#idm140737319192960.)

Comment: Links broken, sadly